# json.parse fails to parse html <p> tag

Tags: c#, html, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a string coming from database which contains < p > tag and I'm passing the whole object which contains this string as well through a viewbag and then I'm doing JSON.parse in my view to get the object, but parsing fails at objects which their data contains those < p > tags and when I remove them it'll be ok, object will be parsed nicely, what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

p.s: the data which contains those < p > tags is saved through ckeditor so I just saved them as they were.

at server I'm doing:

```
var typedArticle = repo_WordArticle.FindBy(x => x.Article_Id == article.Id).FirstOrDefault();
string typedArticleStr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(typedArticle);
ViewBag.TypedArticle = typedArticleStr;
```

at client side I'm doing:

```
var articleViewModel = {};
articleViewModel.typedArticle = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.TypedArticle)');
```

here is the json result from my chrome console:

```
{"RelationshipManager":{},"Id":24,"Equivalent":null,"RootEn":null,"RootFa":null,"Concept":"<p>jhjkhkkhkjh</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
 ","EquivalentState":"APPROVED","RootEnState":"APPROVED","RootFaState":"APPROVED","ConcepttSt    ate":"APPROVED","Article_Id":122,"CreateDate":"/Date(1392042144427)/","LastModifiedDate":"/D     ate(1392468342593)/","Article":{"ArticleType":{"RelationshipManager":{},"Id":2,"Code":"WORD","Value":"واژه","CreateDate":"/Date(1391347841417)/","LastModifiedDate":"/Date(1391347841417)/"},"RelationshipManager":{},"Id":122,"NameEn":"bye","NameFa":"/بای بای","ViewCount":0,"ArticleType_Id":2,"State":"APPROVED","References":null,"ExtraDescription":null,"CreatedBy":"admin","LastModifiedBy":"admin","CreateDate":"/Date(1392042144293)/","LastModifiedDate":"/Date(1392468247317)/"}}
```

Comment: I don't think `<p>` will be as such in json

Comment: can you show me the resultant json ?

Comment: I've edited my question with the result as well,is it because of the new lines? I remove the < p > tags from database and it works fine...